# Android: ContentResolver wont update it's values

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-contentresolver

I am making an android music application, I am using SQLiteDatabase to store the song values after getting them from a query on ContentResolver at OnCreate() of Main activity.

However when I open the Android Device Monitor and push a file or dynamically (`new File(path).delete();`) delete a file, it doesn't get updated in the ContentResolver, if I close the app and launch it again or RUN it again from Android Studio, there is another query at startup yet the deleted songs are still shown and added ones aren't.

Since the files are deleted/added in the ADM properly I suspect this is some problem with ContentResolver not being updated. I only modified my database to add or delete song rows as I figured ContentResolver will be updated on its own. Please help on how I can ensure it is updated.

Also is it a better (and possible) way of getting songs to traverse the file system manually from the root?

Comment: see MediaScannerConnection

Comment: @pskink Thank you for the hint, but using MediaScannerConnection, how do I scan a file that has been deleted? I mean do I just scan the file path it had before it was deleted? Would it work?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm embarrassed to find that the answer was very obvious, but I'll let this question remain in case anybody else has a similar moment of confusion:

First get the file path. As an example:

```
public static String getPath(int position)
    {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
    }
```

So now you have the path stored in a string named path, then you actually delete the file thus:

```
System.out.println(new File(path).getAbsoluteFile().delete());
```

Then you can delete it from the contentresolver manually as it wont get updated immediately otherwise:

```
System.out.println(getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " = '" + path + "'", null));
```

The System out will print the number of content rows deleted or whether the file has been deleted or not on the console, if you need to confirm.